# WSO2 API Manager Trigger Fault Sequence from Out Sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

is it possible manually trigger Fault Sequence from Out Sequence based on endpoint's response message? if so, can anyone point me how to do it?

if it isn't, what is the proper way to make wso2 api manager treat unsuccessful endpoint's business process as fault so that in the statistic, it will not be counted as successful api call

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.You can use sequence mediator to call a sequence even the fault sequence.
Eg:

```
 <outSequence>
     <sequence key="fault"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, if i use the default fault sequence. But if i try using  custom fault sequence that i uploaded from carbon interface, it wont work, it keeps giving me 'Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='mainapi_default_json_fault'} cannot be found' 
*nb : my custom fault sequence is mainapi_default_json_fault.

is there any solution to this?

Comment: If you have uploaded your fault sequence to registry use the key to point that.For example if it governance registry gov:sequences/faulttriggerseq.xml or if it config registry conf:sequences/faulttriggerseq.xml